# Stopping time product of iid random variables

Tags: probability, analysis

Based on this question [Expectation of product of iid random variables limited by stopping time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645346/expectation-of-product-of-iid-random-variables-limited-by-stopping-time). Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be i.i.d. such that $X_i > 0$ and $\mathbb E[X_i]=1$ ($P(X_i=1/3)=1/2=P(X_i=5/3)$) and consider $\mathbb F = \{\mathcal F_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ to be the discrete filtration. Denote $Y_n = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$. For any **bounded** $\tau \in \mathbb F$, we have $\mathbb E[Y_{\tau}]=1$.

Comment: On what do you base your claim that $\mathbb E[Y_{\tau}] = 0$? $Y_n$ is almost surely positive, so that would seem problematic.... Also, the natural guess to me would be $\mathbb E[Y_{\tau}] = 1/18$, but I don't think $\tau$ is almost surely finite so I doubt $E[Y_{\tau}]$ is even defined here.

Comment: Well, if $\tau < \infty$, then $Y_{\tau}$ is (by definition) $1/18$. However, like I said, I don't think $\tau < \infty$ has probability $1$, so I don't think $\mathbb E[Y_{\tau}]$ is well-defined as written.

Comment: $Y_n$ takes values of the form $\frac{5^k}{3^n}$ where $k \in \{0,1,2,ldots,n\}$ so cannot be $\frac1{18}$ with positive probability.   But it can be less than $\frac1{18}$ and the probability of it being so increases towards $1$ as $n$ increases.  You may have intended $\tau:=\inf\{n: Y_n\le 1/18\}$

Comment: I suspect neither, and instead that $E[\tau]$ is finite but clearly more than $1$

Comment: @Qqeisit Do you mean $\mathbb E[\tau]$, or $\mathbb E[Y_{\tau}]$? (These are quite different.)

Comment: We would have $\mathbb E[Y_{\tau}] \leq 1/18$ by definition of $\tau$ (and coupled with the fact that $\tau < \infty$ with probability $1$, which is true but not quite trivial). It is easy to **bound** $\mathbb E[Y_{\tau}]$, but I think actually **computing** the exact value of $\mathbb E[Y_{\tau}]$ would be very difficult.

Comment: Simulation seems to suggest $E[\tau] \approx 11.6$ and $E[Y_{\tau}]\approx 0.0347$

Comment: As a mild curiosity, the simulation points out you cannot have $\tau \in \{1,  2,  4 , 7, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 33\}$ or various other values three or four more than the previous one.  This makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments, I see that your question is whether this conflicts with the Optional Stopping Theorem. The answer is **no**. Your $\tau$ is not bounded, so there's no contradiction.

Note also that your $\tau$ is not only bounded, it doesn't even seem to be almost surely finite; that is, $\mathbb P(\tau = \infty) > 0$. (In fact, I think this probability is *one*.) This results in a number of other problems -- in particular, it's not clear how you would define $Y_{\infty}$, which means that $\mathbb E[Y_{\tau}]$ is also not even clearly defined.

**EDIT**: From other comments, I think you intended for your real stopping time to be $\tau := \inf\{n: Y_n \color{red}{\leq} 1/18\}$ instead. This stopping time would still not be bounded.

For $\tau$ to be bounded, there must exist some $k$ such that $\mathbb P(\tau < k) = 1$. However, for any $k$, there is a positive probability (specifically, a probability of $1/2^k$) that the first $k$ steps are all upward; that is, $X_1 = \dots = X_k = 5/3$). Hence, $\tau$ cannot be bounded.

Comment: This new $\tau$ is at least finite with positive probability (and it might be finite with probability $1$ -- I'd have to think about it). If it is true that $\tau < \infty$ with probability $1$, then we could say $\mathbb E[Y_{\tau}] \leq 1/18$ (we would not be able to say they're equal) -- however, this would still not contradict the Optional Stopping Theorem result, because your $\tau$ would not be bounded (and we can't "assume it's bounded" in much the same way we can't "assume a 6 is a 7").

Comment: As for why it's not bounded: for any positive integer $k$, there is a positive probability that $X_1 = X_2 = \dots = X_k = 5/3$ -- that is, the first $k$ steps all go up. Having $\tau$ be bounded would require that there is some $k$ such that $\mathbb P(\tau < k) = 1$, and that is impossible in this case..

Comment: No, $\tau < \infty$ with probability $1$. The walk $Y_n$ will eventually dip below $1/18$ (hence the walk will stop with probability $1$), but **the number of steps it takes to do so** might be quite large (i.e. is unbounded). A good analogy is: if you repeatedly roll a die, how many rolls will it take you to see your first 6? With probability $1$, this will happen in a finite time, but it might take many tries (such as one million).

Comment: Can we say $\tau=\inf\{n: \log Y_n\le \log(1/18)\}$? So that is $\inf\{n: \sum \log X_i\le \log(1/18)\}$. That becomes a stopping time of a random walk. Let $S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i$ Can we compute the $E[S_{\tau}]$?

Comment: @Qqeisit Simulation works there too since you have not changed the stopping time for $\tau$:  you seem to have $E[S_\tau]=E[\log T_\tau]$ about $-3.41$ which is plausible as it has to be between $\log(1/18)$ and $\log(1/54)$

Comment: Your edit to your question is a fairly huge one that massively changes the problem (and the answer to it). I recommend rolling back the question to the old version (so that the accepted answer makes sense again) and asking new questions **in a new question** rather than putting more questions in the comments here.

Comment: @Qqeisit I should have written $E[S_\tau]=E[\log Y_\tau] \approx -3.41$ simulating $10^5$ cases

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Does it seem that we can apply optional stopping time for $\tau\le \infty$? Because $Y$ is a non-negative martingale.

Comment: @QQesit I rolled back your question to the original so that it references the $\tau$ you are asking about. I see that you did open up another question as I suggested, so I'll answer this question there.