# Stopping time and its expectation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

[Expectation of product of iid random variables limited by stopping time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645346/expectation-of-product-of-iid-random-variables-limited-by-stopping-time?noredirect=1&lq=1)
My last question is confusing... My question is still similar as before.

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be i.i.d. such that $X_i > 0$ and $\mathbb E[X_i]=1$ and consider $\mathbb F = \{\mathcal F_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ to be the discrete filtration. Denote $Y_n = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$. We have the fact that for any **bounded** $\tau \in \mathbb F$ we have $\mathbb E[Y_{\tau}]=1$.

Comment: Small correction to your post: I'm pretty sure you mean $T = \color{red}{\inf}\{n : Y_n \leq 1/18\}$. If not, none of my answer will apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking your related [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4376322/stopping-time-product-of-iid-random-variables) here for posterity.

(1) You are correct that $Y_n$ is a nonnegative martingale. However, the optional stopping theorem does **not** guarantee that $\mathbb E[Y_{\tau}] = 1$ for any stopping time with $\tau < \infty$ almost surely.

For the Optional Stopping Theorem to apply in this way, you need one of three things:

1. A **bounded** stopping time $\tau$ (meaning that there exists some $M$ such that $\tau < M$ with probability 1)
2. An **integrable** stopping time $\tau$ (that is, $\mathbb E[\tau] < \infty$), and a process $X_t$ with **bounded increments** (meaning that there exists some $M$ such that $X_{t+1} - X_t < M$ with probability 1)
3. An **almost surely finite** stopping time $\tau$ , and a **bounded** process $X_t$ (meaning that there is a constant $M$ such that $-M < X_t < M$ with probability 1).

Notice that among these conditions, the heavier a restriction you place on $\tau$, the more you can relax the conditions on $X_t$, and vice versa. Going from condition 1 to 3, you can see that the conditions on $\tau$ relax, while the conditions on $X_t$ tighten.

You asked whether having $\tau < \infty$ with probability 1 was sufficient, but it is not; you need in addition to have a bounded process to guarantee the optional stopping theorem (unless you impose a stronger condition on the stopping time).

(2) With $T = \inf \{n : Y_n \leq 1/18\}$, it is true (though not trivial) that $T < \infty$ almost surely. (Short sketch of proof: consider $\log(Y_n)$, which is a random walk on $\mathbb R$ that takes larger steps downward than upward. In the long run, this will almost surely become less than any value $K$, including $K = \log(1/18)$. Or, an alternate proof: the Martingale Convergence Theorem, which implies that every nonnegative martingale converges almost surely.)

Consequently, it is true, almost by definition, that $\mathbb E[Y_T] \leq 1/18.$ This does not contradict the Optional Stopping Theorem, because the Optional Stopping Theorem does not apply to this stopping time / process.

Note that of the 3 conditions, we can immediately rule out conditions 2 and 3 as possibilities for applying the OST. The process $X_t$ is unbounded above, and even its increments are unbounded -- consider what might happen if the first $n$ steps are all taken in the positive direction. Hence, the only condition that *might* apply is condition 1. However, even that does not apply here; for any $M$, there is a positive probability that the first $M$ steps will all be to the right and that $T < M$ will be false.

Hence, none of the conditions for the Optional Stopping Theorem apply in this case. There is no contradiction.

Now, if you had considered the stopping time $T_2 := \{n : Y_t \leq 1/18 \text{ or } Y_t \geq 5\}$ (or any other positive number for an upper bound), then both condition sets 2 and 3 *would* apply in that case, and we *would* have $\mathbb E[Y_{T_2}] = 1$ for that example.

Comment: Sure -- note that $Y_{\tau - 1} > \frac{1}{18}$, so $Y_{\tau} > \frac 1 {18} \cdot \frac 1 3$.

Comment: Well, I think non-negative super-martingale is bounded because $E X_t\le E X_0$. then $E X_\tau \le E\lim inf X_{\tau\land n}\le E X_0$. Why the non-negative martingale is not bounded?

Comment: Also, for $T<\infty$ a.s. How to get it from  nonnegative martingale converges almost surely?

Comment: I mean for non-negative supermartingale and $T\le \infty$ we have an optional stopping theorem. Is not $Y_n$ a non-negative supermartingale?

Comment: "I mean for non-negative supermartingale and $T \leq \infty$ we have an optional stopping theorem." This is not true. The optional stopping theorem is as I described above, and it does not say anything about nonnegative supermartingales. You might be thinking instead of the martingale convergence theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems), which is a different theorem. Also, a "bounded" martingale must be bounded on *both* sides, not just lower-bounded (i.e. nonnegative).

Comment: As for why this implies $T < \infty$ -- the only way for that process to converge is for it to get close to $0$. If it never drops below $1/18$, then it will frequently have steps upward of at least $1/18 \cdot 5/3$, which means it won't converge.

Comment: Ah, you're right and I was mistaken -- I suppose that sometimes called an Optional Stopping Theorem as well. (This is one of the problems with this name -- multiple things are sometimes called the "Optional Stopping Theorem".) That theorem you cite applies here, and it states that $\mathbb E[X_0] \geq \mathbb E[X_\tau]$; this should make sense here, because $\mathbb E[X_0] = 1$ and $\mathbb E[X_\tau] \leq 1/18$.